# Can I force MySQL to transmit numerical values as binary?

Tags: c++, mysql, c, database, mysql-connector

I've been investigating network performance of our MySQL/C++ application. I found that our clients read all values (ints, doubles, etc.) from the MYSQL C-Connector in ASCII literals. That means that the server is transmitting numbers to the clients as text (eg. the String "123" for the int 123). All of our data in this application consists of numerical values (ints and doubles), so I am wondering:

Is there a way to force the MySQL server to transmit the numerical values in binary format rather than ASCII?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean that. It may only mean that the connector is transforming binary to text.

Comment: Fair point, so is there a way to tell the connector not to perform the transformation from binary to text?

Answer (score 0):

Use a compressed connection. Look for `UseCompression` in [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-connection-options.html)

Comment: I considered this, but it seems that this option would result in a lot of unnecessary conversions. ie, at the server side: binary to ASCII, then compress; at the client side: decompress, and convert from ASCII to binary. If we could forgo these 4 operations then we'd save valuable CPU cycles on both server and client sides.

Comment: You're making some pretty bold assumptions about what is and isn't efficient. Have you actually benchmarked anything here, or are you just guessing?

Comment: Did you benchmark the application with compression enabled? When dealing with networks, often the bottleneck is the physical link, not the compression/decompression (which is quite common, indeed). What kind of network are you referring to? A Gigabit Ethernet fiber link or a sloppy 56k modem connection?)

Comment: We've previously been running this application on our company network, so a Gigabit connection, we're adding some clients that will be connected via an ADSL connection (well, at least that's the slowest link). We've benchmarked the application extensively in the past to get to where we are, but I'm adding the compression functions to the benchmark tests now, as I only recently became aware of that option.

Comment: We are benchmarking the compression option now. Initial indications show that with compression enabled the network traffic is reduced to around 30% of it's uncompressed size, so that's definitely a positive result. Time required to perform the queries has increased by approximately 35% but I've not yet drilled down to see exactly where that extra time is being spent.

Comment: A more exhaustive benchmarking exercise demonstrated that although  enabling compression reduced network traffic by nearly 70%, it nearly doubled our average query time under a broad range of test conditions. With this in mind I'd still like to explore the option of sending the numerical data in binary format direct from MySQL if possible.